# Using setBackground correctly

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

Hopefully an easy one for you...

I've been trying to set the background color of a QtListWidgetItem, but I'm not having much luck - this is probably because I'm not using the QListWidgetItem correctly... In my test code I can set the foreground of every third item in the list, but setting the background seems to have no effect. Can anyone spot my stupid error?

I've tested this out with both PyQt4 and PySide on Qt 4.7

Thanks, Dan

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class List(QtGui.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(List, self).__init__()
        self.populate()

    def populate(self):
        for i in range(32):
            item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(self)
            item.setText('%d'%i)

            if i % 3 == 0:
                brush = QtGui.QBrush()
                brush.setColor(QtGui.QColor('red'))
                item.setBackground(brush)

            if i % 3 == 1:
                brush = QtGui.QBrush()
                brush.setColor(QtGui.QColor('blue'))
                item.setForeground(brush)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    listw = List()
    listw.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't really need a brush. Just use a `QColor`:

```
item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor('red'))
```

Comment: Yup - that does it, thanks! - This'll teach me to follow the [documentation](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QListWidgetItem.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QListWidgetItem.setBackground)...

Comment: If you want a nifty hint, you can get rid of *all* the `QtBlah.Foo` stuff and replace it with just `Foo` if you import Qt4 like so: `from PyQt4.QtCore import *` and `from PyQt4.QtGui import *`. It makes things a bit more readable, as you don't need to type `QtCore.` and `QtGui.` anymore.

Comment: PyQt4 has built in variables instead of having to hardcode strings. `QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.black)`

Comment: `QColor` also supports hex color codes, such as `QColor('#efefef')`.